# force:createRecord issue in winter 18 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience

We are facing issue while using "force:createRecord" event in lightning. Its working for Standard object when we are giving entityApiName as "Account" but on the same hand if we are doing it with custom object its not working.

Working:-

```
 ({
createRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
     var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");

    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Account"                  
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
})
```

Not Working:-

```
({
createRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
     var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");

    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "CustomeObj__c"                        
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
})
```

Comment: I recommend you file a case with support on this.

Comment: My custom object createRecord event is working fine in my org.  Is your component in one.app container ? ( I know that you said it is working fine for Standard objects but just to recheck. )

Comment: Hello @brahmajitammana, we overrided custom object's new button with our component. As you said its working in your org, can you please tell do you have winter 18?

Comment: Did this event work for you before the winter18 release?

Comment: Yes @ItaiShmida, it was working before winter18.

Comment: Try some other custom objects - if all have same symptoms - this is a bug so try opening a case, if not - this is somehow related to this specific object...

Comment: one more observation, if we are overriding standard new button then it is causing this problem. We created new action and linked it to our lightning component, its working. Strange behavior :( –

Comment: @ArpitSethi Did you find any solution for this ? I observed this issue in my sandbox. force:createRecord is working till summer 17 and from winter 18 it is considering overridden standard action.

Comment: @brahmajitammana, We have logged a case in salesforce, waiting for the response

Answer (score 1):

This is a winter 18 known issue. Check [this](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EFOoQAO&title=when-attempting-to-create-a-new-record-after-firing-the-force-createrecord-event-the-page-will-go-in-a-loop) link for more. Fixed in most of the data centers and release is in progress.